# Firebase Analytics API StatusRunTimeException with XdsInitializationException

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics, grpc-java

My problem - when start runReportRequest catched exeptions: StatusRunTimeException, XdsInitializationException. It is problem exist only when start jar-file, and when start in IDE that's ok and problem doesn't exist. Full log error:

янв. 08, 2023 8:49:41 PM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener handleErrorInSyncContext
WARNING: [Channel<1>: (analyticsdata.googleapis.com:443)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Failed to initialize xDS, cause=io.grpc.xds.XdsInitializationException: Cannot find bootstrap configuration
Environment variables searched:

- GRPC_XDS_BOOTSTRAP
- GRPC_XDS_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG

  `Java System Properties searched:
- io.grpc.xds.bootstrap
- io.grpc.xds.bootstrapConfig
  at io.grpc.xds.BootstrapperImpl.bootstrap(BootstrapperImpl.java:110)
  at io.grpc.xds.SharedXdsClientPoolProvider.getOrCreate(SharedXdsClientPoolProvider.java:87)
  at io.grpc.xds.XdsNameResolver.start(XdsNameResolver.java:179)
  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.exitIdleMode(ManagedChannelImpl.java:418)
  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel$2.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:981)
  at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
  at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:978)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcChannelUUIDInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcChannelUUIDInterceptor.java:52)
  at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:80)
  at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:54)
  at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:920)
  at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$AffinityChannel.newCall(ChannelPool.java:514)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.newCall(ChannelPool.java:143)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:99)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:60)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.futureCall(GrpcUnaryRequestParamCallable.java:65)
  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:87)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41)
  at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedUnaryCallable.futureCall(TracedUnaryCallable.java:75)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
  at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.runRealtimeReport(BetaAnalyticsDataClient.java:672)
  at ru.vkcleanlite.ApplicationKt.getRealtimeReport(Application.kt:87)
  at ru.vkcleanlite.ApplicationKt$startRequests$1.run(Application.kt:135)
  }
  com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Failed to initialize xDS`

Initialization:

```
BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create().use { analyticsData ->
        val request = RunRealtimeReportRequest.newBuilder()
            .setProperty("properties/$propertyId")
            .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("city"))
            .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("activeUsers"))
            .build()


        val response = analyticsData.runRealtimeReport(request)
    }
```

How, I see, need add environment variables GRPC_XDS_BOOTSTRAP GRPC_XDS_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG, but where get this is files? Official guide shared links on Git, where source link unsaffed, browser denied. But in this time, I'm not sure, what problem in environment variable, because in IDE that's all work, and in quick start (offical firebase guide for GA4) not contains information about settings for grps-connection. Pehraps, my research incorrect and problem another. For now updated grpc, but it not fixed problem. How it fixed? Thanks!

Comment: How do you create BetaAnalyticsDataClient? Did you intend to use xDS?

Comment: @YuriGolobokov Hello! I now add initialization in main post

Comment: @YuriGolobokov Please help me with solution, if you know